# How to modify info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

So i need to disable ATS in my xcode project by typing

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
```

in my info.plist. However my info.plist file contains only

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>LastAccessedDate</key>
    <date>2022-11-06T09:15:11Z</date>
    <key>WorkspacePath</key>
    <string>/Users/markmarus/Desktop/name/name.xcodeproj</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There also is a scm.plist which contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Version</key>
    <integer>5</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After adding ATS settings and starting simulator up the info.plist file just deletes added lines so it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The `Info.plist` generated by Xcode starts with a uppercase letter and contains much more information than your obviously self-generated one.

If you want to modify the Xcode `Info.plist` do it the GUI in the `Info` tab of the target. After adding a custom key-value pair it appears also in the project navigator and you can open it as *Source Code* to modify the property list text directly.